# Approval Process on custom object - lock the record on the status

Tags: approval-process

Is that possible to restrict/lock the record on a specific status?
I have few status when those status changed I want to lock the record so user does not change the record, I'm not sure if this is possible using declarative or do I have to use Trigger any help ?

for an example, if my status is changed to "complete" or "void" or "rejected" than lock the record.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with an approval process? Why not a Validation Rule?

More generally, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I already have approval process implemented, I'm asking if this is possible doing the declarative or require programmatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to lock a record is using an Approval Process. The locking feature is a standard feature provided by Salesforce and the entire record will be locked.

You just need to setup an Approval Process for an object (in this case, your custom object) and set the criteria for the record to enter the approval process (the stages you would like to lock). Once you set the initial criteria, the Initial Submission Action will include Record Lock.

[image]

[image]

You can set the record edit ability settings to ‘Administrators’ only OR currently assigned approver.